# How to make variant id change in url when selecting product options

Tags: shopify, product, product-variations

I think I'm working with an old theme since new themes seem to have a js file already in place to update the variant ID in the URL upon making options selections for a product. I've been trying to figure it out but I'm totally lost. The theme I have doesn't seem to have anything like that at all.

I have been trying different things with jQuery to get the variant ID values from the options and `history.pushState` to change the id in the URL but it's not the greatest solution and doesn't work consistently, nor it is a true "fix."

As much as I would like to just change the theme to a newer, working one, that's sadly not an option, and I am aware this theme is probably terrible.

Here is the site: https://elizabethsuzann.com/collections/all-products

Here is the product file:

```
    <div id="content" class="main-content">
    <div id="page">
        <div class="row full-width clearfix">
            <div id="product-{{ product.id }}">
                <div class="column medium-6 large-6 product-photos product__images left show-for-small-only">
                    {% include "product-toggler" %}
                </div>
                <div class="column medium-6 large-6 product__description right" id="product-right">
                    <div id="product-description">
                        <div class="row product__details">
                            <div class="column medium-9">
                                {% if settings.vendor %}<h3>{{ product.vendor }}</h3>{% endif %}
                                <h1 class="product__title medium-text-left small-text-center">{% include "product-title-replacer" %}</h1>
                                <h2 class="product__fabric medium-text-left small-text-center">
                                    {% include 'tag-looper' %}
                                </h2>
                                <div class="yotpo bottomLine"
                                     data-appkey="ydEHp58GjhymPiIi6x0gT4BYZjK5cAQOeGanUwmT"
                                     data-domain="{{ shop.permanent_domain | escape }}"
                                     data-product-id="{{ product.id }}"
                                     data-product-models="{{ product.id }}"
                                     data-name="{{ product.title | escape }}"
                                     data-url="{{ shop.url }}{{ product.url }}"
                                     data-image-url="{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'large' |replace: '?', '%3F' | replace: '&','%26' }}"
                                     data-description="{{ product.description | escape }}"
                                     data-bread-crumbs="{% for tag in product.tags %}{{ tag | escape }};{% endfor %}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="spacer-20"></div>
                                {% if settings.subtitle %}<p>{{ page_title }}</p>{% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="column medium-3">
                                {% if product.available %}
                                    {% if product.compare_at_price > product.price %}
                                        <h3 class="product-price product__price medium-text-right small-text-center onsale"
                                            itemprop="price"><span
                                                    style="color:#f46e6e;">{{ product.price | money }}</span>
                                            <br>
                                            <span class="compare-price was"
                                                  style="text-decoration: line-through;">{{ product.compare_at_price | money }}</span>
                                        </h3>
                                    {% else %}
                                        <h3 class="product-price product__price medium-text-right small-text-center"
                                            itemprop="price">{{ product.price | money }}</h3>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    <!--OUT OF STOCK!-->
                                {% else %}
                                    <h3 class="product-price product__price medium-text-right small-text-center soldout-text"
                                        itemprop="price">Sold Out</h3>
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="https://elizabethsuzann.com/pages/contact" target="_blank"
                                           class="ask-a-question-product">Ask A Question
                                        </a>
                                    </p>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% include 'short-form' %}
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="product__accordions text-editor">
                            <ul class="accordion" data-accordion id="productAccordion">
                                <li class="accordion-navigation active">
                                    <a href="#panel1a">Description</a>
                                    <div id="panel1a" class="content active">
                                        {{ product.description | replace: '<h5>', '</div></li><li class="accordion-navigation"><a href="#panela">' | replace: '</h5>', '</a><div id="panela" class="content">' }}
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        {% if settings.popups %}
                            <div class="product__modals">
                                <ul class="inline-list">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" data-reveal-id="sizeChart">Size Chart</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" data-reveal-id="returnPolicy">Return Policy</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" data-reveal-id="question">Ask A Question</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column medium-6 large-6 product-photos product__images left show-for-medium-up">
                    {% include "product-toggler" %}
                    {% include "customer-slideshow" %}
                </div>
                <div class="show-for-small-only">{% include "customer-slideshow" %}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="product-single-extras">
    {% if settings.diversity_slideshow_enable %}
        {% assign hasDiversity = false %}
        {% for image in product.images %}{% assign alt_text = image.alt %}{% if alt_text contains "DIVERSITY_" %}{% assign hasDiversity = true %}{% endif %}{% endfor %}
        {% if hasDiversity == true %}
            <div class="full-width row collapse diversity-panel">
                <div class="small-12 columns diversity-panel-container">
                    <div>{% for image in product.images %}{% assign alt_text = image.alt %}{% if alt_text contains "DIVERSITY_" %}
                            <img src="{{ image | img_url: 'master' }}"
                                 alt="{{ alt_text | remove: 'DIVERSITY_' | replace: '\"', '$quot;' }}"/>{% break %}{% endif %}{% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <ul class="diversity-panel-details brandon"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}

    {% assign hasSlides = false %}
    {% for image in product.images %}
        {% assign alt_text = image.alt %}
        {% if alt_text contains "SLIDESHOW" %}
            {% assign hasSlides = true %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if settings.product_slideshow_enable and hasSlides == true %}
        <div class="full-width row collapse image-slideshow">
            <div class="small-12 columns">
                <div class="loader">
                    <div class="load-watch">
                        <div class="slider">
                            {% for image in product.images %}
                                {% assign alt_text = image.alt %}
                                {% if alt_text contains "SLIDESHOW_" %}
                                    <div>
                                        {% if alt_text contains "http://" or alt_text contains "https://" %}
                                        <a href="{{ alt_text | remove: 'SLIDESHOW_[[' | remove: ']]' }}">{% endif %}
                                            <img src="{{ image | img_url: 'master' }}"
                                                 alt="{{ alt_text | remove: 'SLIDESHOW_' }}"/>
                                            {% if alt_text contains "http://" or alt_text contains "https://" %}
                                        </a>{% endif %}
                                    </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% include 'related-products-tag' %}
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="yotpo yotpo-main-widget" data-product-id="{{ product.id }}" data-name="{{ product.title | escape }}"
     data-url="{{ shop.url }}{{ product.url }}"
     data-image-url="{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: "large" |replace: '?', '%3F' | replace: '&','%26' }}"
     data-description="{{ product.description | escape }}"></div>
{{ 'inStockAlerts.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
{{ 'extendedSizes.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

collection file:

```
    <!-- /snippets/collection-sidebar.liquid -->
<div id="page" class="row full-width">
      {% if collection.image %}
      <div class="full-width row collapse collection-header-image">
          <div class="small-12 columns">
            <div class="loader">
               <div class="load-watch">
                   {% if collection.image.alt contains "[a]"%}
                        {% assign altTextArray = collection.image.alt | split: "[a]" %}
                        {% assign urlArray = altTextArray[1] | split: "[/a]"%}
                   {% endif %}
                   {%if urlArray[0] %}<a href="{{ urlArray[0] }}" title="{{collection.title}}">{%endif%}
                      <img src="{{ collection.image | img_url: 'master' }}" alt="{{ collection.image.alt }}">
                   {%if urlArray[0] %}</a>{%endif%}
               </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>{% endif %}
      <div class="row show-for-small-only">
        <div class="column text-center"><h1>{%if collection.title != "Materials" %}{{ collection.title }}{% else %}{%if current_tags.first %}{{current_tags.first}}{% endif %}{% endif %}</h1></div>  
        <div class="spacer-30"></div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div id="content" class="full-width">
        {% paginate collection.products by 21 %}
          <!-- START SIDEBAR -->
            {% include 'sidebar-collection' %}
          <!-- END SIDEBAR -->
          <div class="column medium-9 large-10 main-content" id="product-collection"> 
            {% if collection.description.size > 0 %}
                <div class="collection-description text-editor hide-for-small">
                    {{ collection.description }}  
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            
            <ul class="small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-3 xxlarge-block-grid-4">

              {% for product in collection.products %}
                  <li class="product-index" id="prod-{{ product.id }}" data-alpha="{{ product.title }}" data-price="{{ product.price }}">
                          <div class="product-index-inner">
                            {% if product.available %}
                              {% for col in product.collections %}
                                {% if col.handle == 'new' %}
                                <div class="new icn">NEW IN</div>
                                {% endif %}
                              {% endfor %}

                              {% if product.price < product.compare_at_price %}
                              <div class="sale-item icn">SALE</div>
                              {% endif %}

                            {% else %}
                            <div class="so icn">SOLD OUT</div>
                            {% endif %}             
                        </div>
                        <div class="image_hover">
                                <div class="loader">
                                  <div class="load-watch">
                                  <a href="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.url | within: collection }}" title="{{ product.title | escape }}" style="display:block;">
                                    {% for image in product.images %}
                                        {% if forloop.first %}
                                          <img class="variant-image" src="{{ product.images[0] | product_img_url: 'master' }}" alt="image.alt" data-holder="{{ product.images[0] | product_img_url: 'master' }}" />
                                        {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                  </a>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              {% if product.available %}
                                  {% assign v_image = false %}
                                  {% for vimage in product.variants %}
                                      {% if vimage.image %}
                                        {% assign v_image = true %}
                                        {% endif %}
                                  {% endfor %}

                                  {% if v_image %}
                                    <div class="variants" style="padding: 5px;">
                                      {% for option in product.options %}
                                        {% assign opt_index = -1 %}
                                          {% if option == 'Color' %}
                                            {% assign opt_index = forloop.index0 %}
                                          {% endif %}
                                          {% if opt_index > -1 %}
                                            {% assign color_done = '' %}
                                            {% for variant in product.variants %}
                                                {% assign color = variant.options[opt_index] %}
                                                {% assign colorFirst = color | split: ' ' %}
                                                {% for coloring in colorFirst %}
                                                    {%if forloop.first%}
                                                        {% assign colorClass = coloring %}
                                                    {%endif%}
                                                {% endfor %}
                                                {% unless color_done contains color %}
                                                    {% assign color_image = color | downcase | replace: ' ','-' | append: '.png' %}
                                                    {% if variant.image %}
                                                        <div class="variant {{ colorClass | downcase }}{% if forloop.first %} active{% endif %}" data-link="{{ product.url | within: collection }}?variant={{ variant.id }}" data-variant="{{ variant.image | img_url: 'original' }}" title="{{ variant.title }}" style="background: url({{ color_image | asset_url }});"></div>
                                                    {% endif %}
                                                    {% assign color_done = color_done | append: color | append: ',' %}
                                                {% endunless %}
                                            {% endfor %}
                                          {% endif %}
                                      {% endfor %}
                                    </div>
                                  {% endif %}
                              {% endif %}
                        </div>    

                        <div class="product-info"> 
                          <div class="product-info-inner row"> 
                            <div class="column medium-8 small-text-center medium-text-left">

                                {% if settings.vendor %}<h4><a href="{{ product.url }}"> {{ product.vendor }}</a></h4>{% endif %}
                                <h3><a href="{{ product.url }}">{% include "product-title-replacer" %}</a></h3>
                                  <h2 class="product__fabric medium-text-left small-text-center">
                                  {% include "tag-looper" %}
                                  </h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column medium-4 small-text-center medium-text-right">
                                <div class="price">
                                  {% if product.price < product.compare_at_price %}
                                  <div class="onsale">{{ product.price | money }}</div>
                                  <div class="was" style="display:block;">{{ product.compare_at_price | money }}</div>
                                  {% else %}
                                  <div class="prod-price">{% if product.price_varies %} from {{ product.price_min | money }} - {{ product.price_max | money }} {% else %}{{ product.price | money }}{% endif %}</div>
                                  {% endif %}   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                  </li>
              {% endfor %} 

            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="column text-center">
                <div id="pagination"> 
    <!--           <span class="count">Showing items {{ paginate.current_offset | plus: 1 }}-{% if paginate.next %}{{ paginate.current_offset | plus: paginate.page_size }}{% else %}{{ paginate.items }}{% endif %} of {{ paginate.items }}.</span> -->

              {% if paginate.previous %}
              {{ '<' | link_to: paginate.previous.url }}
              {% endif %}
              {% for part in paginate.parts %}
              {% if part.is_link %}
              {{ part.title | link_to: part.url }}
              {% else %}
              {% if part.title == '&hellip;' %}
              {{ part.title }}
              {% else %}
              <span class="current">{{ part.title }}</span>
              {% endif %}
              {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
              {% if paginate.next %}
              {{ '>' | link_to: paginate.next.url }}
              {% endif %}
                </div>
          </div>
        {% endpaginate %}
      </div>
</div>
```

And the custom js file that I've been working in:

```
var extendedSizes = (function () {
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
// request.open("GET", "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8573/files/models.xml?12460120219966895535", false);
request.open("GET", "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8573/files/models.xml?428914189903248951", false);
request.send();
var xml = request.responseXML;
var models = [].slice.call(xml.getElementsByTagName('Model'));
var colorButton = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#colors .swatch-element'));
var thumbnails = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnail'));

if ($('#physical-gift-card').length < 1) {
    var initialAlt = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnail'))[0].getAttribute('alt');
}


var name, height, bust, waist, hip, size, onClick, clickAlt, color, colorAlt;
var destination = $('.zoomer');

// Primary function for getting data and calling appendMeasurements to append it
function measurements(alt, size) {
    for (var i = 0; i < models.length; i++) {
        if (models[i].hasAttribute('name')) {
            name = models[i].getAttribute('name');
            // If clicked thumbnail alt matches a model in the XML doc
            if (alt.indexOf(name) > -1 && alt.length > 0) {
                var children = models[i].childNodes;
                // Nested loop to get child attributes
                for (var t = 0; t < children.length; t++) {
                    switch (children[t].nodeName) {
                        case 'Height':
                            height = children[t].firstChild.nodeValue
                            break;
                        case 'Bust':
                            bust = children[t].firstChild.nodeValue
                            break;
                        case 'Waist':
                            waist = children[t].firstChild.nodeValue
                            break;
                        case 'Hip':
                            hip = children[t].firstChild.nodeValue
                            break;
                    }
                    appendMeasurements(name, height, bust, waist, hip, size)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Append size/fit measurements after image gallery with updated grammar for it with fallback


function appendMeasurements(name, height, bust, waist, hip, size) {
    $(destination).find('.extended-sizes-model-text').remove();
    if (typeof size != 'undefined') {
        var grammarA = ['S', 'M', 'L', '2XL', '3XL', '4XL'];
        var grammarAN = ['XL', 'XXS', 'XS', 'OSM', 'OS', 'OSP', 'OSP2', 'OSP3'];
        if ($.inArray(size, grammarAN) !== -1 || ($.inArray(size, grammarA) == -1 && $.inArray(size, grammarAN) == -1)) {
            $(destination).append("<div class='extended-sizes-model-text'><p>" + name + " is " + height + " tall with a " + bust + " bust, " + waist + " waist, and " + hip + " hip," + " and she is wearing an " + size + ".</p> </div>")
        }
        if ($.inArray(size, grammarA) !== -1) {
            $(destination).append("<div class='extended-sizes-model-text'><p>" + name + " is " + height + " tall with a " + bust + " bust, " + waist + " waist, and " + hip + " hip," + " and she is wearing a " + size + ".</p> </div>")
        }

    } else {
        $(destination).append("<div class='extended-sizes-model-text'><p>" + name + " is " + height + " tall with a " + bust + " bust, " + waist + " waist, and " + hip + " hip." + "</p> </div>")
    }

}

// Run on default
if ($('#physical-gift-card').length < 1) {
    if (initialAlt.indexOf('-') > -1) measurements(initialAlt.split('- ')[1]);
}
// Run measurements function on thumbnail click
thumbnails.forEach(function (img) {
    img.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        var clicked = event.target;
        clickAlt = clicked.getAttribute('alt');
        // console.log(clickAlt.split('-'));
        // console.log(clickAlt.split('-').slice(-1).pop());
        if (clickAlt.split('-').length > 2) {
            var size = clickAlt.split('-').slice(-1).pop().trim();
        }
        onClick = true;
        if (clickAlt.indexOf('-') > -1) clickAlt = clickAlt.split('- ')[1];
        measurements(clickAlt, size);
    })
})

// Run measurements function each time SELECT COLOR is clicked
colorButton.forEach(function (button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        color = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-color');
        colorAlt = $('.product-photos').find("." + color).find('.product__sideimages').find('img:first-child:first').attr('alt');
        // console.log(colorAlt.split('-'));
        if (colorAlt.split('-').length > 2) {
            var size = colorAlt.split('-').slice(-1).pop().trim();
        }
        if (initialAlt.indexOf('-') > -1) measurements(colorAlt.split('- ')[1], size);
        var selectorDropdown = $(".select option:selected").val();

        console.log("color: "+color);
        if (history.pushState) {
            var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + "?variant=" + selectorDropdown;
            window.history.pushState({path: newurl}, '', newurl);

        }
    })
})

// all varient selection add to cart class change
var sizeListItem = $('div.swatch > #sizes > li');
var lengthListItem = $('div.swatch > #length > li');

var sizeClicked = false;
var lengthClicked = false;

sizeListItem.each(function (e){
    $(this).on("click", function() {
        $(this).addClass('size-selected');
        console.log('at least one size list item selected');
        sizeClicked = true;

        var variantClass = $(this).find("input").attr("class");
        var availabilityState = $(this).find(".swatch-element");
        var emailBtn = $(".swym-add-to-watchlist");

        if (history.pushState) {
            var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + "?variant=" + variantClass;
            window.history.pushState({path: newurl}, '', newurl);

            if (availabilityState.hasClass("soldout") || availabilityState.hasClass("unavailable")) {
                emailBtn.show();
            }
            else {
                emailBtn.hide();
            }
        }
    });
})

lengthListItem.click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('length-selected');
    console.log('at least one length item selected');
    lengthClicked = true;

    var variantClass = $(this).find("input").attr("class");
    var availabilityState = $(this).find(".swatch-element");

    if (history.pushState) {
        var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + "?variant=" + variantClass;
        window.history.pushState({path: newurl}, '', newurl);

        if (availabilityState.hasClass("soldout") || availabilityState.hasClass("unavailable")) {
            emailBtn.show();
        }
        else {
            emailBtn.hide();
        }
    }
});


if ($('#length').length > 0) {

    setInterval(function () {
        if ((lengthClicked === true) && (sizeClicked === true)) {
            $('.product__add').addClass('atc-activate');
            $('.product__description .product__add .disabled').css({
                'background': '#000',
                'color': '#fff'
            })
        }
        // console.log(true);

    }, 100);
} else {

    setInterval(function () {
        if ((sizeClicked === true)) {
            $('.product__add').addClass('atc-activate');
            $('.product__description .product__add .disabled').css({
                'background': '#000',
                'color': '#fff'
            })
        }
        // console.log(true);

    }, 100);
}


})();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function:

```
function updateQueryString(key, value, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;

    let updated = ''
    var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|#|$)(.*)", "gi"),
        hash;

    if (re.test(url)) {
        if (typeof value !== 'undefined' && value !== null) {
            updated = url.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2$3');
        } 
        else {
            hash = url.split('#');
            url = hash[0].replace(re, '$1$3').replace(/(&|\?)$/, '');
            if (typeof hash[1] !== 'undefined' && hash[1] !== null) {
                url += '#' + hash[1];
            }
            updated = url;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (typeof value !== 'undefined' && value !== null) {
            var separator = url.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '&' : '?';
            hash = url.split('#');
            url = hash[0] + separator + key + '=' + value;
            if (typeof hash[1] !== 'undefined' && hash[1] !== null) {
                url += '#' + hash[1];
            }
            updated = url;
        }
        else {
            updated = url;
        }
    }

    window.history.replaceState({ path: updated }, '', updated);
}
```

The functionality is fairly simple. Just pass `variant` and the variant's `id`, like this:

`updateQueryString('variant', '123123');`

If the URL does not have the `?variant` query string yet, it will automatically create it. If it does, it will update it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not getting correct value for current selected product variant.

```
var selectorDropdown = $(".select option:selected").val();
```

`selectorDropdown` is always having value `"12893562601560"`

If you take a closer look at your select options, no option is selected.

Just check that your `selectorDropdown` value is correct and it should work fine.

PS: I took ref. of https://elizabethsuzann.com/collections/all-products/products/georgia-tee-midweight-linen?variant=12893562601560

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
`$('select').on('change', function() {
 var variantId = $(this).find(":selected").val();
 $("a").attr('href', '/cart/'+ variantId +':1');
});`
```